# Keyboard input doesn't work properly when using hosting Qt widget on CDialog with QWinWidget

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I'm gradually migrating application from **MFC** to **Qt** and using **MFCMigrationFramework** for this purpose.

Qt widget which is placed on MFC dialog doesn't handle such keys as **Tab**, **Arrows**, **Enter**, **Esc**.
Issue with Tab and arrows was partially solved with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066183/qwinwidget-inside-mfc-dialog-not-repainting-or-responding-to-tab-arrow-keys):

I've subclassed **QWinWidget** and have made next things:
Constructor:

```
SetWindowLong(winId(), GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(winId(), GWL_STYLE) | WS_TABSTOP);
```

Overriden winEvent:

```
bool winEvent(MSG *msg, long *result)
{
  switch(msg->message)
  {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
      *result = DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTTAB;
      return true;
  }

  return __super::winEvent(msg, result);
}
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode

It works except one issue: it's impossible to reach controls on parent dialog (MFC) using **Tab** key, focus cycles only through child Qt control (**the first issue**).

**The second issue**: **Enter** and **Esc** keys are handled only by parent MFC dialog. For instance, it's impossible to close opened popup of combobox (located on Qt widget) by pressing Enter or Esc key - dialog is closed instead (**CDialog::OnOK** or **CDialog::OnCancel** is called).

I've tried this

```
case WM_GETDLGCODE:
  *result = DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTTAB | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
```

but in this case **CDialog** doesn't handle Esc and Enter keys anymore.

What is the right solution to handle such situation?

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your first issue: what worked for me is to decide, based on the current focus point, if you're at an "endpoint" in the focus chain. If you are at the end and get a tab (or at the beginning and get a shift-tab), then don't include **DLGC_WANTTAB** in your return value:

```
else if (msg->message == WM_GETDLGCODE)
{
  // Initialize our result, as we always want arrows
  *result = DLGC_WANTARROWS;

  // Check to see if we want tabs
  if (msg->wParam == VK_TAB)
  {
    // Was this a tab or a backtab?
    QWidget *pFocusChainEndpoint = NULL;
    if (::GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0)
    {
      pFocusChainEndpoint = m_pFirstTabStop;
    }
    else
    {
      pFocusChainEndpoint = m_pFinalTabStop;
    }

    // Determine our current-focusing widget
    QWidget *pCurrent = focusWidget();
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
      // We have no focus, so we don't want the tab event
      return true;
    }

    // If we are *not* at a relevant endpoint in the focus chain,
    // we want to handle the tab event
    if (pCurrent != pFocusChainEndpoint)
    {
      *result |= DLGC_WANTTAB;
    }
  }

  // This message has been handled
  return true;
}
```

`m_pFirstTabStop` and `m_pFinalTabStop` are determined in the `show()` code:

```
  // Determine the first link in our focus chain
  m_pFirstTabStop = nextInFocusChain();
  Q_ASSERT(m_pFirstTabStop != NULL);
  if (m_pFirstTabStop == NULL)
  {
    // We have no endpoint
    return;
  }
  QString qstrChainObjectName = m_pFirstTabStop->objectName();
  while (!(m_pFirstTabStop->focusPolicy() & Qt::TabFocus)
    || qstrChainObjectName.left(3) == "qt_")
  {
    m_pFirstTabStop = m_pFirstTabStop->nextInFocusChain();
    if (m_pFirstTabStop == this || m_pFirstTabStop == NULL)
    {
      // We've looped through them all, and none require focus --- perhaps the
      // control is just labels --- so we have a NULL tab stop
      m_pFirstTabStop = NULL;
      return;
    }
    qstrChainObjectName = m_pFirstTabStop->objectName();
  }

  // Determine the last link in our focus chain
  m_pFinalTabStop = previousInFocusChain();
  Q_ASSERT(m_pFinalTabStop != NULL);
  if (m_pFinalTabStop == NULL)
  {
    // We have no endpoint
    return;
  }
  qstrChainObjectName = m_pFinalTabStop->objectName();
  while (!(m_pFinalTabStop->focusPolicy() & Qt::TabFocus)
    || qstrChainObjectName.left(3) == "qt_")
  {
    m_pFinalTabStop = m_pFinalTabStop->previousInFocusChain();
    if (m_pFinalTabStop == this || m_pFinalTabStop == NULL)
    {
      // We've looped through them all, and none require focus --- perhaps the
      // control is just labels --- so we have a NULL tab stop
      m_pFinalTabStop = NULL;
      return;
    }
    qstrChainObjectName = m_pFinalTabStop->objectName();
  }
```

Though I didn't test this case, it should be able to properly handle a UI with only non-tabbable controls (e.g. just QLabels).